# How I can increase or decrease the size of an ImageView?

Tags: android

I would like to know how to enlarge an image that is already in the `ImageView`.

I have this:

```
m_imageView.setImageBitmap(imagen); 
int newHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight() / 2;
int orgWidth = m_imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
int orgHeight = m_imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
int newWidth = (int) Math.floor((orgWidth * newHeight) / orgHeight);
//Use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams if your parent is a RelativeLayout
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                newWidth, newHeight);
m_imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
//m_imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);
```

But it does nothing, the image remains the same.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

did you invalidate the view? with invalidate() or postInvalidate() on your activity?

Comment: No, but I hand putting the values ​​"params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams LinearLayout.LayoutParams (newwidth, newHeight)," I got it to work.

Now I'm trying to put the image on the top right. How could it?

Comment: try this: `m_imageView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT); m_imageView.setVerticalGravity(Gravity.TOP); `

Comment: Uhm... my ImageView don't have setGravity.